Virtual Reality movie about a man rediscovering his dead ex wife
I've been trying to find a movie, which I saw years ago but would love to find again.
The film starts with a newly married couple in their car. They're parked up and meet a bunch of unsavoury people from afar. Something is said and the the man responds, a situation transpires and his wife is murdered.
Years later the man lives a life of solitude, and is invited to use a newly developed piece of virtual reality technology. He plays around with technology and one of the first scenes shows a surface with an apple on it.
The film develops and he occasionally sees flashbacks of his dead wife through the virtual reality (VR) machine. Later he finds out through an executive of the company whom develops the VR machine, the machine reads your subconscious thoughts and introduces those elements found.
Time goes by and he finds himself enthralled by his dead wife. Eventually pulling himself away from the machine with the help of a friend. The film ends with man and his friend walking through a city centre, it's empty as the VR machine has now been released and the whole world is absorbed into their VR machines.

Is this British, American, or ?? About when did you see the film and when does it look like it's from?

American, about 10 years ago I saw the film, and it looks like a borderline TV movie


Virtual Seduction (1995)
Edited from this review:

Journalist Liam Bass has been a shattered man ever since felons raped and murdered his fiancee, Paris, and left him for dead during
  their elopement two years ago.
Laura [a close friend and reporter] frets when shell-shocked Liam
  volunteers to be a test subject for the experimentation conducted by
  virtual-reality whiz Dr. Grant.



Feeling he has little to lose, Liam welcomes the installation of a VR
  pod in his apartment. After an intruder tampers with the device,
  Liam experiences fantasies of Paris over which he has no control. 



Liam spends more and more time in the pod. He flees reality to relive his past, rewriting history to destroy Paris's killers in his
  unconscious. 
Laura and Anderson [one of the VR programmers] discover that Dr. Grant
  ordered the alterations in the VR machine; Grant's microchips now
  have direct access to Liam's memories...

The only available videos (in English) are country-restricted to the US and UK. I noticed that you're from Liverpool, so you are off the hook :-) 
Watch the trailer or the full movie to confirm if it's the right one.
~ Poster from Amazon; Screenshots from X8 (1)(2)
